# Combining rand() and srand() for better performance

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, dll, random

So, I am making a DLL that I want to have a function to generate random numbers. I was wondering which of these options is more efficient (performance wise).

This one is just making a function in a DLL that allows me to get a random number.

```
int getRand(unsigned int seed) {
    int rNum;  // Random Number.

    srand(seed);
    rNum = (rand() % // Whatever I need here.
}
```

Or, would just using `srand(time(nullptr))` and `rand()` in the application be better in performance?

Thanks,

Johnny P.

Comment: Calling `srand()` right before `rand()` each time does not make sense. `srand()` is used to _seed_ the sequence of random numbers. Use it only once in the beginning.

Comment: Before worrying to death about micro-optimization, you would probably benefit a lot more from learning the fundamentals of how PRNGs work! Or, as the saying goes, "it's easier to make good code fast than to make fast code good".

Comment: @jogojapan Why don't I? I thought I had to seed it every time I wanted a random number so that I don't get the same number every time?

Comment: `rand()` updates the internal state of the random number generator each time. So you want get the same number again (or only by co-incidence sometimes of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really any need to create a function that combines a call to `srand()` with one to `rand()`.

`srand()` is used to seed (i.e. to initialise) a sequence of random numbers. Subsequent, and repeated, calls to `rand()` are then used to actually generate the random numbers. (`rand()` updates the internal state of the random number generator, so it (generally) won't generate the same number again when called the next time.)

If you call `srand()` each time before you call `rand()`, the sequence will be re-initialised each time. If the seed passed is the same each time, your function will return the same random number *each time*.

**Therefore, the two calls will have to be separated anyway.**

You may also be interested in the random number generation framework provided by the `<random>` header in C++11. Here is example code (mostly copied from cppreference):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  /* Initialise and seed. Do this only once. */
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());

  /* Define how to use the raw random numbers, i.e.
     a probability distribution. In this case a
     uniform distribution with six possible integer
     events. */
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

  /* Generate a series of random events. No reseeding. */
  for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
      std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

cppreference has a pretty good description of the `<random>` header and the many options it provides: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.

Most of this is inspired by the Boost random library, which provides even more options: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random.html (Link to the 1.52.0 version). Therefore, if you can't use C++11, or you need functions not provided by the Standard, using the Boost library may be a good idea.

Comment: I never knew C++11 had a framework for this! Thanks! Do you have any more info on this framework?

Comment: @Tux I've included some links.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway I could get a link to all the new C++11 features?

Comment: @Tux There are _many_ new features... One way to start is to look at a list of them (e.g. here the list of C++11 features supported by GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html, or the Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and then search for the names of these features on SO. Neither compilers nor textbooks are quite up to date yet, so some features (e.g. regular expressions) are very hard to use at this point.

Comment: Thanks, definitely will start using these new features when possible!